# Does Dimension Door up, then Feather Fall work as I expect?

Tags: dnd-5e, teleportation, falling

My character wants to impress a person by teleporting 500' up with Dimension Door together with them, then casting feather fall to spend the next almost a minute (500' / 60' = landing on 9th round) admiring the scenery and conversing privately.

Does this work as expected?

---

My own thoughts:

Dimension Door up should be unproblematic (it takes a special kind of DM to roll for bird impact here).

My main worry is, does the Feather Fall, cast as reaction when falling, activate immediately at 500' giving the full "flight time".

Then landing should again be problem-free, right?

Any hazards I am not aware of, assuming there are no hostiles shooting at the falling characters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## There's no reason not to expect this to work

There are no general rules on when you start falling (PHB only covers damage and covers rate) so it works using the DM's common sense. After you cast *dimension door* you are not supported by anything (unless you've landed on the back of bird or similar) so you would fall. When you fall you can use your reaction to cast *feather fall*:

> which you take when you or a creature within 60 feet of you falls

Getting pedantic on the wording, that reaction is only at the start of a fall, as that's when you fall. Otherwise it should be "as a creature is falling" or similar. If they do decide to get pedantic or introduce detail though, that's on them because the game rules don't get specific.